# OpenLayers in MVC map not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openlayers

I'm trying to display an open layers map into the website, but the map on MVC website is not showing not even the zoom buttons. but on a normal notepad with the same code the map is showing and I can't find what's the problem. Can someone help me please?

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            init();
        });

        var map, layer;
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection

        function init() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map("map")

            var osmlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
            map.addLayer(osmlayer);

            var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("NASA Global Mosaic", "http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi", { layers: "modis,global_mosaic" });
            map.addLayer(wms);

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.505787300000065, 35.8760686).transform(fromProjection, toProjection), 9);
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Home</h2>
    <div id="mainPage">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the rendering of your page. Look at the source code generated in your browser, the div with the id="map" could have been renamed by ASP and the new OpenLayers.Map("map") is then not pointing to the right container object.